# Как в java в JSlider увеличить размер самого ползунка (указателя)?

Tags: java

Пишу в NetBeans приложение на Java, как можно наиболее простым способом увеличить размер самого ползунка(указателя) в JSlider (не всего компонента)?

[image: Форма]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class SliderThumbSize extends JPanel {
    public SliderThumbSize() {
        super(true);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);

        UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
        defaults.put("Slider.thumbHeight", 50);
        defaults.put("Slider.thumbWidth", 50);
        slider.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);

        slider.setLabelTable(slider.createStandardLabels(10));

        add(slider, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {}

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Slider Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new SliderThumbSize());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: прописываю в качестве look and feel - Metal или Windows, заменив в вышеприведенном коде Nimbus на Metal или Windows. в результате размер thumb(указателя) перестает меняться. как можно изменять размер thumb используя тему Metal или Windows?

Comment: Не все темы поддерживают эту возможность.